# Constructing a date for getRequestedUpdateDateWithHandler:

Tags: swift, watchos, apple-watch-complication, clockkit

I need to update my watchOS complication at midnight every day.

`startOfDay` is the beginning of the day (i.e., 12 AM today).

Should I add a day to the start of today like this?

```
func getNextRequestedUpdateDateWithHandler(handler: (NSDate?) -> Void) {
    // Call the handler with the date when you would next like to be given the opportunity to update your complication content
    let startOfDay = NSDate().startOfDay
    let components = NSDateComponents()
    components.day = 1
    let startOfNextDay = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingComponents(components, toDate: startOfDay, options: NSCalendarOptions())
    handler(startOfNextDay)
}
```

Or should I not add a day to the code, and just do something like this:

```
func getNextRequestedUpdateDateWithHandler(handler: (NSDate?) -> Void) {
    // Call the handler with the date when you would next like to be given the opportunity to update your complication content
    let startOfDay = NSDate().startOfDay
    handler(startOfDay)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want to advance the date one day, since you want your next requested update to occur at *tomorrow's* midnight. The first method would do what you want, but you can simplify it as follows:

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let startOfDay = calendar.startOfDayForDate(NSDate())
let startOfNextDay = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: 1, toDate: startOfDay, options: NSCalendarOptions())!
```

The second code would return today's 12 AM, which would already be in the past.